# Vue.js export default object scope

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Could anyone please explain that the scope of `export default` within vue files? Thank you.

Example:

`HelloWorld.vue`

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <HelloWorld />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}

console.log(HelloWorld) // ReferenceError: HelloWorld is not defined
</script>
```

```
App.vue
```

```
<template>
  <div id="app">

    <HelloWorld />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import HelloWorld from "./components/HelloWorld";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}

console.log(HelloWorld) // HelloWorld is defined
</script>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to import the component itself from inside the component definition?

Comment: Because I get confused the scope of export default.

Comment: it would cause an infinite loop if its allowed

Comment: @lun It has nothing to do with scope. *HelloWorld is just not defined* yet as the error is telling you at the point when you do `console.log` in `HelloWorld` component.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use a component inside itself then you are looking for a recursive component https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Recursive-Components.
You can achieve this by changing the name option value in HelloWorld.vue to a unique value.(Notice both HelloWorld.vue and App.vue have the same name)

Note: Recursively using a component can result in an infinite loop so make sure to do so with a conditional that would result to a falsey value at some point in time.

Finally, the reason you have a ReferenceError isn’t because of the scope of export default. It is because you are using the component before it is defined. To solve this, you can use webpack’s asynchronous import(remember to change component name value to be unique as well). To do asynchronous imports, remove the import statement you have in the top of the script section then import the component like so:

```
components: {
      HelloWorld: () => import('./components/HelloWorld.vue')
}
```

Note: I am assuming you are using a webpack build system here.

Answer (score 1):

The `export default` is used to create local registration for Vue component.